# Change context path format

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

While creating "REST API" in WSO2 API Manager, in the "Create an API" page, this message is displayed

> "**API will be exposed in {context}/{version} context at the
>   gateway**"

which means say an API is created with context as "/testapi" and version as "1.0" will be exposed as `"/testapi/1.0".` 
Is it possible to change the context format in which API is exposed at WSO2 API Manager, say, `"/1.0/testapi"` or hide the version part? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the default version approach which allows you to omit the version part in the url you can use 'context templates' to achieve a context like '/1.0/testapi'.

When defining the context for the api give it as /{version}/testapi and define the version in version field as 1.0.[image]

This will create an API with following gateway URL.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can publish your current API version as [default version](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/learn/design-api/api-versioning/backward-compatibility/#default-version), then you do not need to provide the version when invoking.